# Series solution does not match numerical solution

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

I have a system of algebraic-differential equations (for background see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461866/41145)):
$$
2 a'(u)=u x'(u),\\
4 a(u)^2 \left(3 u^2 x(u)^2+1\right)=4 x(u) \big(u a(u)+4 x(u)\big)+1.
$$

with initial conditions $a(0)=-1/2, x(0)=0$. It can be nicely solved numerically

```
{ka, kx} = 
  NDSolveValue[{2 Derivative[1][a][u] == u Derivative[1][x][u], 
    4 a[u]^2 (1 + 3 u^2 x[u]^2) == 1 + 4 x[u] (u a[u] + 4 x[u]), 
    a[0] == -1/2, x[0] == 0}, {a, x}, {u, 0, 1000}];
```

Since I am interested in the behaviour of $a(u)$ at $u\rightarrow\infty$, and I suspect that the leading term of $a(u)$ must be $-1/u$, I seek a solution in the forms of series:

```
m = 7;
a[s_] := -1/s + Sum[A[i]/s^i, {i, 3, m, 2}]
x[s_] := Sum[B[i]/s^i, {i, 0, m, 2}]
eqs = Series[{2 Derivative[1][a][u] == u Derivative[1][x][u], 
     4 a[u]^2 (1 + 3 u^2 x[u]^2) == 1 + 4 x[u] (u a[u] + 4 x[u])}, {u, Infinity, m - 1}] // Normal;
{sol} = SolveAlways[eqs, u];
```

Now, the solutions can be compared:

```
Plot[{a[s] /. sol, ka[s]}, {s, 0, 20}]
```

and

```
Plot[{x[s] /. sol, kx[s]}, {s, 0, 20}]
```

[image] . . . .  [image]

As you can see, the series solution for $a$ nicely match its numerical result. However, the series solution for $x$--does not match the respective numerical result. I would like to know if this is a problem with the default solver of `NDSolveValue`, or am I doing something wrong mathematically?

Comment: Can you please re-check your code with `NDSolveValue`? [I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZKu5.png) a $x\equiv0, a\equiv-1/2$ solution ...

Comment: I assume you might have not cleared the definitions for `x` and `a` before running `NDSolveValue`.

Comment: @Domen I have checked. I really get what is in OP.  My version is 13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022).

Comment: I get an `ndsz` error after the first few steps. If I differentiate the algebraic equation, I get results that look like above. Changing precision and integration method does not alter the `NDSolve` results significantly. However, FWIW, changing the initial value of `x[0]` changes the limit that the numerical `x[s]` approaches: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[NDSolveValue[{2 Derivative[1][a][u] == u Derivative[1][x][u], D[4 a[u]^2 (1 + 3 u^2 x[u]^2) == 1 + 4 x[u] (u a[u] + 4 x[u]), u], a[0] == -1/2, x[0] == x0}, x[s], {u, 0, 100},  Method -> Automatic], {x0, Range[0, 10]/10}], {s, 0, 20}]`

Comment: I am on version 13.3.0 for Win64. I get the same result as Domen for the `NDSolveValue` (ie constants), and I can only reproduce the blue curve in the series result.

Comment: Note that `x'[u]` goes to zero as `u` goes to infinity. I think any value for `x` can be a limit of `x[u]` at infinity. I don't know the math behind the `Series` approach -- why it says `B[0] -> 1/2` and whether that's wrong. It *seems* wrong, though.

Comment: Specifying initial derivatives works for me (Mac, V13.3.1): `{ka, kx} = 
 NDSolveValue[{2 Derivative[1][a][u] == u Derivative[1][x][u], 
   4 a[u]^2 (1 + 3 u^2 x[u]^2) == 1 + 4 x[u] (u a[u] + 4 x[u]), 
   a[0] == -1/2, x[0] == 0, a'[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1/16}, {a, x}, {u, 0,
    1000}]`

Answer (score 4):

*[Update: I needed to recalculate the initial $a(0)$ for each different initial $x(0)$, so that the solution starts on the algebraic equation.]*

If I rework the OP's approach with a differentiated algebraic equation, then the asymptotic solution is different and matches the numerical solution better. I don't understand the math. This sort of analysis is missing in my background. The following shows how well the asymptotics (color) match the numerics (dashed black), and (***update***) how well the algebraic equation is solved out to "infinity" (10^6):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this is not cheating: The match shows that there is a numerical solution matching each asymptotic solution and vice versa. What happens is this. The asymptotics of differentiated system `sol2` has a free parameter `B[0]`, the limit at infinity.  I solved for that parameter 11 times using the numerical solution for $x(0) = 0.0, 0.1,\dots, 0.9, 1.0$, and (***update***) solved for $a(0)$ using the algebraic equation.  If the asymptotics are a good model, they should match, which they seem to. I don't know how to solve for the limit at infinity in terms of $x(0)$, except by numerically integrating a long way. (***Update:*** Use of `DSolveChangeVariables` to switch $u=\infty$ to $0$ omitted, because of some silly activation issue means at the moment no access to V14/13.3. :/)

Sorry I can't explain the math better, but I hope this helps in some way.  The comparison made it seem I was probably on the right track, and I wanted to share it in case it's helpful. `Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {aeq}}` in `NDSolve` does better at satisfying the algebraic equation, but there's no significant qualitative difference.

Code:

```
m = 7;
aa[s_] := -1/s + Sum[A[i]/s^i, {i, 3, m, 2}]
xx[s_] := Sum[B[i]/s^i, {i, 0, m, 2}]
eqs = Series[{
      2 Derivative[1][a][u] == u Derivative[1][x][u],
      D[4 a[u]^2 (1 + 3 u^2 x[u]^2) == 1 + 4 x[u] (u a[u] + 4 x[u]), 
       u]} /.
     {a -> aa, x -> xx},
    {u, Infinity, m - 1}] // Normal;
sol2 = SolveAlways[eqs, u];

xx[1000.] /. sol2 (* inspect solution for large u *)
(*
{-9.99997*10^-7 + 1.66667*10^-18 A[5],
 -1.*10^-6 + 1. B[0] + 3.*10^-12/(1 + 6 B[0]) + (2.*10^-17 (1 + 7 B[0]))/(1 + 6 B[0])^3}
*)

ode = {2 Derivative[1][a][u] == u Derivative[1][x][u], 
   D[
    aeq = 4 a[u]^2 (1 + 3 u^2 x[u]^2) == 1 + 4 x[u] (u a[u] + 4 x[u]), 
    u]};
inf = 10^6;
sols = Join @@ Table[NDSolve[{
       ode,
       {a[0] == (a[0] /. 
           FindRoot[aeq /. u -> 0 /. x[0] -> x0, {a[0], -1/2}, 
            WorkingPrecision -> 40]), x[0] == x0}
       }, {a, x}, {u, 0, inf}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, 
      InterpolationOrder -> All], {x0, 0, 1, 1/10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.33258, Null}*)

Plot[{xx[s] /. sol2[[2]] /. B[0] -> (x[inf] /. sols), x[s] /. sols} //
    Flatten // Evaluate
 , {s, 0, 20}
 , PlotStyle -> Join[
   Table[Hue[3 i/(4 Length[sols])], {i, 0, Length[sols] - 1}],
   Table[
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]; Dashed, Black], {Length@sols}]
   ]
 , PlotLegends -> Append[N[x[0] /. sols], HoldForm[x]], 
 ImageSize -> 360, PlotLabel -> "Asymptotic vs. Numerical"]

LogLogPlot[
 ((xx[s] /. sol2[[2]] /. B[0] -> (x[inf] /. sols)) - (x[s] /. 
        sols))/(x[s] /. sols) // Abs // Evaluate
 , {s, 0, inf/10}
 , PlotStyle -> Join[
   Table[Hue[3 i/(4 Length[sols])], {i, 0, Length[sols] - 1}], 
   Table[
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]; Dashed, Black], {Length@sols}]]
 , PlotLegends -> N[x[0] /. sols], ImageSize -> 360, 
 PlotLabel -> "Relative Error", WorkingPrecision -> 40]

LogLogPlot[
 (Subtract @@ aeq /. sols) // Abs // Evaluate
 , {u, 0, inf}
 , PlotStyle -> Join[
   Table[Hue[3 i/(4 Length[sols])], {i, 0, Length[sols] - 1}], 
   Table[
    Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]; Dashed, Black], {Length@sols}]]
 , PlotLegends -> N[x[0] /. sols], ImageSize -> 360, 
 PlotLabel -> "Residual Error in Algebraic Equation", 
 WorkingPrecision -> 40]
```

Comment: I seems to understand your approach better. By solving two ODE you are not able to determine `B[0]` and therefore resort to numerics. My question would be, at $u=\infty$, does it fulfil the algebraic equation?

Comment: @yarchik A good point. You're probably right to doubt that.

Comment: @yarchik See if the update satisfactorily addresses your point.

Comment: Thanks for your update. There is a lot of information, but I think the conclusion should be that my series solution uses unjustified assumption that $a\sim-1/u$.